# Apply draggable="false" to all images at once with CSS

Tags: css, draggable

In order to prevent from users dragging images on my website, it seems I have to do like this : `<img draggable="false" src="../example.jpg" style="width:100%">`.

But I have a bunch of images to apply to, so I wonder if there is a way to apply it for all images in CSS.

Answer (score 1):

You cant do this with css. But you can do it via JS (jQuery in this example)

```js
$('img').attr('draggable', false);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<img src="https://via.placeholder.com/50x50">
<img src="https://via.placeholder.com/50x50">
<img src="https://via.placeholder.com/50x50">
<img src="https://via.placeholder.com/50x50">
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do it with this CSS:

```
user-drag: none; 
user-select: none;
-moz-user-select: none;
-webkit-user-drag: none;
-webkit-user-select: none;
-ms-user-select: none;
```

Comment: This will not work in Firefox. `-webkit-user-drag` is the only property that can be used to avoid dragging. The `user-select` property has no effect on dragging an element.

Answer (score 0):

Changing behavior & interactivity of elements is not really what CSS is supposed to be for (it's for handling layout & appearance).

You can set `user-drag` and `user-select` (and browser variations) CSS properties on all images, or you can use CSS selectors to access & manipulate a group of elements with a given class or ID, instead of directly targeting every element of that type. Since you don't seem to have any CSS classes on your images, you have to target the `img` element, which currently would affect every image on the page.

You could do this with basic JavaScript (see snippet) or jQuery:

```
$('img').attr('draggable', false);
```

If, for example, you later want to make only a certain group/type of images draggable, you could apply a CSS class to them and use it to target only images with that class instead of changing the properties of *every* `img` element.

```js
//get all images & make them all non-draggable
var allImages = document.getElementsByTagName("img");
    for (element of allImages) { 
        element.draggable = false;
        //console.log(element.draggable);
    }
    
//make only images w/the appropriate CSS class draggable again    
var draggableImages = document.getElementsByClassName("draggableImage");
    for (element of draggableImages) { 
        element.draggable = true;
        //console.log(element.draggable);
    }
```

```css
img {
  width: 60%;
}

.draggableImage {
   /*Whatever styles you might want to apply to a draggable image  */
}
```

```html
<img draggable="true" src="http://via.placeholder.com/300x20"></img>

<img draggable="true" src="http://via.placeholder.com/300x20"></img>

<img class="draggableImage" draggable="true" src="http://via.placeholder.com/300x20"></img>

<img class="draggableImage" draggable="true" src="http://via.placeholder.com/300x20"></img>
```

Answer (score 0):

> Is there a way to apply it for all images in CSS?

No, there is no cross browser way to do it with CSS only.

There's `-webkit-user-drag`, but it won't work in Firefox.

Answer (score 0):

### **Prevent all dragging**: (all browsers, no jQuery)

```js
addEventListener('dragstart',function(e){e.preventDefault()});
```